# about .plan! How to execute programs within the .plan file

Tags: linux

I am currently learning LINUX commands and I am wondering how to run commands within the .plan file.
For example i want to a message as would be output from the ~stepp/cosway programs.
I typed ~stepp/cosway "HELLO" but it didn't work. What is the command for that?

Also how do I set all files in the current directory and all its subdirectories recursively to have a group of admin?

Answer (score 1):

The [.plan](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/P/plan-file.html) file is a plain text file that is served by the [fingerd](http://www.manpagez.com/man/8/fingerd/) daemon. For security reasons, it's not possible to execute commands from that file, unless you modify and recompile `fingerd` on your machine to do so.

Concerning the second part of your question, use [chgrp](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/chgrp/):

```
$ chgrp -R admin *
```

Comment: Thank you very much! btw which book would you suggest to read to get familiar with linux?

Comment: You can find *a lot* of online documentation [here](http://tldp.org/guides.html).